# I want to do operator overloading in c++ and it is giving error

Tags: c++

```
*#include<iostream.h>

class complex
{
    int a,b;
    public:
    complex(int x,int y)
    {
        a = x;
        b = y;
        cout<<"a and b is\n"<<a<<b<<endl;
    }
    complex operator+(complex ob)
    {
        complex t;
        t.a=a+ob.a;
        t.b=b+ob.b;
        return(t);
    }
};

int main()
{
    complex a(5,6);
    complex b(7,8);
    complex c;
    c = a+b;
    return 0;
}
```

I am facing that error:

```
ll.cpp: In member function âcomplex complex::operator+(complex)â:
ll.cpp:15: error: no matching function for call to âcomplex::complex()â
ll.cpp:7: note: candidates are: complex::complex(int, int)
```

Comment: You need to write default constructor.

Comment: Exactly what the error message says.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have no default constructor, change your operator implementation to not require one:

```
complex operator+(complex ob)
{
    ob.a += a;
    ob.b += b;
    return ob;
}
```

Note that `ob` is copied into the function, so you already have a local, private object that's yours to use as you please.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this constructor to your code

```
complex()
{
  a = 0;
  b = 0;
}
```

Comment: Ugh. Why assign when you can initialize?!

Comment: This is my preference when writing constructors. That way, I can see the values of a new instance clearly. Maybe I could change them to 1,1 later on and it would be easier.